# Searching BeautifulSoup after text, need to get all data from table row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="test" class="tablesorter">
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>Major Lazer</td>
  <td class="right">64</td>
  <td>93.1.15.107</td>
  <td>0x0110000105DAB310</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
</tr>

<tr class="odd">
  <td style="background: #8FB9B0; color: #8FB9B0;">0&#160;</td>
  <td>Michael gunin</td>
  <td class="right">64</td>
  <td>57.48.41.27</td>
  <td>0x0110000631HDA213</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
  <td class="center">No</td>
</tr>

...

</table>
```

This table has over 100 rows, in the same format. What I want to do is to search after the long id, and then find that table row and get the IP and name.

For example, search after: 0x0110000105DAB310
Then find the specific table row in which this text exists, and grab the rest of the info like: Major Lazer and 93.1.15.107

```
table = playerssoup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
  td = tr.find('td', text='0x0110000101517CC6')
```

This shows me the td, but I don't know from here what to do.

Comment: save all the table data inside pandas dataframe and it will be easier for getting the data compared to approach you are following

Comment: What you can do is search for that particular word and after that if you find that word on that particular `tr` then simply fetch the parent tag of that text by using `td = tr.find('td', text='0x0110000101517CC6').parent` then you can simply split the text by `td` and access those index number whose data you want to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `find_previous_sibling('td')`

**Ex:**

```
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find('td', text='0x0110000105DAB310')
    if td is not None:
        print( td.find_previous_sibling('td').text )
        print( td.find_previous_sibling('td').find_previous_sibling('td').find_previous_sibling('td').text )
```

Comment: Awesome! Works and I can take it from here further, thank you !